# When does CDI injection happen?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, cdi

I am working with Wildfly server and am wondering when does the injection actually happen. Is it in the time when it's needed or is there some mechanism to do dependency resolution earlier?
 
If I use annotation `@Inject`, I know that I would get an error if something cannot be injected (ambiguity, etc). Does that mean that injection is done in deployment time? If so, how does that relate to this scenario: suppose I have `BeanOne` which injects `BeanTwo`, and `BeanTwo` injects `BeanThree`. Does this mean that this chain of beans will be allocated in deployment time? What happens if I have many chains than this, and suppose my bean pool is limited to some small number, say 2? How could it be done in the deployment time when there are not enough beans and some of them would have to wait for their dependencies?

Is this case different from programmatic lookup of beans: `CDI.current().select(MyStatelessBean.class).get();`
or even injection using instances: `@Inject Instance<MyStatelessBean> bean;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you are getting are usually coming from what is called a validation phase. That's done during deployment and does not mean the actual beans would be created.

In fact, the bean creation is usually done lazily, especially when proxy is in play (e.g. any normal scoped bean). This is Weld-specific and other CDI implementations do not need to adhere to that as the specification itself does not demand/forbid it.

In practice this means that when you `@Inject Foo foo;` all you get is actually a proxy object. A stateless 'shell' that knows how to get hold of the so called contextual instance *when needed*. The contextual instance is created lazily, on demand, when you first attempt to use that bean which is usually when you first try to invoke a method on it.

Thanks to static nature of CDI, at deployment time, all dependencies of your beans are known and can be validated, so the chain you had in your question can be verified and you will know if all those beans are available/unsatisfied/ambiguous.

As for dynamic resolution, e.g. `Instance<Bar>`, this is somewhat different. CDI can only validate the initial declaration that you have; in my example above, that a bean of type `Foo` with default qualifier. Any subsequent calls to `.select()` methods are done at runtime hence you always need to verify is the instance you just tried to select is available because you can easily select either a type that is not a bean or a bean type but with invalid qualifier(s). The `Instance` API offers special methods for just that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is, then, CDI.current().select(MyStatelessBean.class).get(); and '@Inject Instance<MyStatelessBean> bean; the same', with second just having that initial validation? And what about pooling? If, e.g. I have '@Stateless' bean that I want to inject as part of some long chain of beans (as described above). Should the code calling the bean through proxy have to wait until container gets free bean from pool? I have concurrency of ejbs in mind here.

Comment: Yes, `CDI.current()` is basically a way to get `Instance<T>` for current bean archive. As for pooling, CDI itself doesn't know pooling; that's EJB feature and as a matter of fact, it doesn't even need to exist (servers can resolve that differently). There is a an integration layer between EJB and CDI which allows you to use EJB beans as if they were CDI; in WFLY there is a kind of facade over real EJB instances that Weld uses to allow for this. So the real question is more about how WFLY handles pooling or if it simply always gets you new instances. That I know not.